# Get Row count of child class in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes which looks like :

```
class NumberPattern {

String name
String desc

static hasMany = [dns : NumberPatternDNs]

static mapping = {
    table 'ni_regexp_ud_def'
    version false
    name column: 'NAME'
    desc column: 'DESCRIPTION'
    id column: 'REGEXP_UD_DEF_PK'
 }

}
```

And

```
class NumberPatternDNs implements Serializable{

String dn

static belongsTo = [pattern : NumberPattern]

static mapping = {
    table 'ni_regexp_ud_match'
    dn column : 'DN_VALUE'
    version false
    pattern column : 'REGEXP_UD_DEF_FK'
    id composite: ['pattern', 'dn']
 }

}
```

Now i am doing `NumberPatter.findAll()` which returns me all the rows of parent class and child class(for corresponding FK value).**What i want is instead of getting child rows ,i should only get row count**.
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in what format do you need the row count, so here is one option

```
NumberPattern.findAllByName('name').collect { np ->
    [numberPattern: np, dnsCount: np.dns.size()]
}
```

or, if you need all data in one map:

```
NumberPattern.findAllByName('name').collect { np ->
    new HashMap(np.properties) + [dnsCount: np.dns.size()]
}
```

or you can use hql queries:

```
NumberPattern.executeQuery("select np.id, count(dns) " + 
    "from NumberPattern np left join np.dns dns  " + 
    "where dns.pattern = np and np.id = xyz group by np")
```